# Rails: how do you access belongs_to fields in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the MVC structure below, how can I access `:category`? I added it to the list of `attr_accessible` and restarted the server, but calling `p.category` still doesn't return anything. I'm sure you Rails experts will know what's going on. Thanks in advance!

**Model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :frame
  belongs_to :style
  belongs_to :lenses
  attr_accessible :description, :price
end
```

**View**

```
<% @product.each do |p| %>
<%= p.category %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def sunglass
  @product = Product.all
end
```

Comment: The `p.category` returns a Category object, or nil if the product has no category associated with. You can try `<%= p.category.inspect %>` to show the category if it exists

Comment: Ah, okay. So I tried `p.category.inspect` and everything is indeed nil. But I just established these associations (manually) in dbconsole. I wonder why they aren't showing up.

Comment: You can set a category to a product in the console like this: `Product.where(:id => 5).first.update_attributes(:category => Category.where(:id => 3).first)`

Comment: did you have "has_many" inside Category?

Comment: No. Just `attr_accessible :name`.

Comment: does your objects `product` have a category associated with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify which column of `categories` table you want to display. For example, a column called `name`:

```
<% @product.each do |p| %>
 <%= p.category.name %>
<% end %>
```

Otherwise it will return the object... in other words, all the columns `{id: 1, name: 'blabla', etc }`

Also,

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This definition:

```
belongs_to :category
```

just define a reference point to table Category for every object of Product model. Example your Category model has some column like: name, type,...

One product belongs to one category, and Category has many products. Now, how do you find category's name of a product? You can not write like this:

```
product.category # this is just reference to Category table
```

You should write like this:

```
product.category.name # this will get category's name which product belongs to
```

If you want to get type of category (example):

```
product.category.type
```